# Updating MKButton 'withText' value upon state change

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native, and working on an experimental app where I'm using MKButton from React Native Material Kit.

Based on my limited knowledge, I've constructed the `MKButton` in following way:

```
const AddButton = MKButton.coloredButton()
    .withText('ADD').build();
class AddUpdateUser extends Component<Props> 
{
    ....
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.addButton}>
                <AddButton onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}/>
            </View>
        );
}
```

Above works good. I also wants to update that button's label based on a state field - I tried following way(s) but none worked:

```
const AddButton = MKButton.coloredButton()
    .withText(getButtonLabel).build();

const getButtonLabel = () =>
{
    if (!this.props.updateUser)
    {
        return 'ADD';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'UPDATE';
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
const getButtonLabel = () =>
{
    if (!this.props.updateUser)
    {
        return 'ADD';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'UPDATE';
    }
}

const AddButton = MKButton.coloredButton()
    .withText(getButtonLabel()).build();
```

Best practice is to define `getButtonLabel` first, but I think the reason it's not working for you is that `getButtonLabel` is defined as a function so you need the parenthesis after.  You might need to use curly brackets for the JSX compiler as well, but without trying I'm not 100% sure (eg: `.withText({getButtonLabel()}).build();`)

---

Edit. Now we've looked at your full file, it seems that you've not added the methods within the Class definition.  So let's move the `getButtonLabel` method to be encapsulated within the Class.  This will allow you to access the `props` which are getting passed to the Class:

```
class AddPerson extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Add',
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
        <Icon name={'plus'} size={75} style={{color: tintColor}} />
    )
};

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) 
{
    return nextProps.toUpdate != this.props.toUpdate;
}

getButtonLabel = () => {
    if (!this.props.toUpdate)
    {
        return 'ADD';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'UPDATE';
    }
}

onAddButtonPress()
{
    const newOrModifiedPerson = {
        first_name: this.state.first_name,
        last_name: this.state.last_name,
        phone: this.state.phone,
        email: this.state.email,
        company: this.state.company,
        project: this.state.project,
        notes: this.state.notes
    };

    if (!this.props.toUpdate)
    {
        this.props.createNewContact(newOrModifiedPerson);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('PeopleList');
    }
    else
    {
        this.props.updateContact(newOrModifiedPerson);
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{this.props.toUpdate ? 'Update Details' : 'Add New Person'}</Text>
                <MKTextField textInputStyle={styles.fieldStyles}
                    placeholder={'First Name'} value={this.props.first_name}
                    tintColor={MKColor.Teal}
                    onChangeText={first_name => this.setState({first_name})}/>
                <MKTextField textInputStyle={styles.fieldStyles}
                    placeholder={'Last Name'}
                    tintColor={MKColor.Teal}
                    onChangeText={last_name => this.setState({last_name})}/>
                <MKTextField textInputStyle={styles.fieldStyles}
                    placeholder={'Phone Number'}
                    tintColor={MKColor.Teal}
                    onChangeText={phone => this.setState({phone})}/>
                <MKTextField textInputStyle={styles.fieldStyles}
                    placeholder={'Email'}
                    tintColor={MKColor.Teal}
                    onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})}/>
                <MKTextField textInputStyle={styles.fieldStyles}
                    placeholder={'Company'}
                    tintColor={MKColor.Teal}
                    onChangeText={company => this.setState({company})}/>
                <MKTextField textInputStyle={styles.fieldStyles}
                    placeholder={'Project'}
                    tintColor={MKColor.Teal}
                    onChangeText={project => this.setState({project})}/>
                <MKTextField textInputStyle={styles.fieldStyles}
                    placeholder={'Notes'}
                    tintColor={MKColor.Teal}
                    onChangeText={notes => this.setState({notes})}/>
                <View style={styles.addButton}>
                    <AddButton onPress={this.onAddButtonPress.bind(this)}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

So you see how that method is now inside your Class?  This will give you access to `this.props` which you wouldn't have had outside of it.

Comment: `.withText(getButtonLabel()).build()` able to call the method. But `props` is coming undefined since the method and button declared as `const` outside of the class parenthesis. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post your full file with the Class definition?

Comment: Thank you for your updates. I modified the codes per your suggestion - I also updated the code link that I've shared with the same. The AddButton is still declaring outside of the class file, and doing so calling `.withText({this.getButtonLabel()}).build()` or `.withText(this.getButtonLabel()).build()` throws error as the method is not defined. Only `.withText(this.getButtonLabel).build()` do not throws error but it do not creates any label either.

Comment: I should have actually given a clearer example in the code I put above, but basically you need to bring ALL of your methods etc inside of the class so that they aren't encapsulated.

Comment: Moving AddButton declaration inside the class throws compiler errors pointing to the declaration: https://image.ibb.co/dc8p2J/Screenshot.png. If I remove the `const` or replace `const` with `static` that error do not come, but throws another error `ReferenceError: AddButton is not defined` because of this usage `<View style={styles.addButton}><AddButton onPress={this.onAddButtonPress.bind(this)}/></View>`.

Answer (score 0):

The only doable thing to the above issue I've found is this - which requires more writing and to match regular CSS:

```
<MKButton
  backgroundColor={MKColor.Teal}
  shadowRadius={2}
  shadowOffset={{width:0, height:2}}
  shadowOpacity={.7}
  shadowColor="black"
  onPress={() => {
    console.log('hi, raised button!');
  }}
  >
  <Text pointerEvents="none"
        style={{color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold',}}>
    RAISED BUTTON
  </Text>
</MKButton>
```

With above usage one can update the `MKButton`'s label at runtime. But I doubt if there's any way to update the label at runtime with the use of `.build()`. What a pity for so popular framework.